# Nested Text Components Props

Tags: react-native

In React Native, I am trying to output a small blurb that generally takes up 2-3 lines of text. In this text, I want some parts to be bolded and pressable, and so I have come up with the following approach to separate the normal text and the special text:

```
<Text>
  <Text style = {{fontSize:12}}>
    {"Tried "}
  </Text>
  <Text style = {{fontSize:12}}>Beef and Shrimp Fried Noodle </Text>
  <Text style = {{fontSize:12}}>{"for $10.25 at "}</Text>
  <Text style = {{fontSize:12}}>JoyYee Restaurant</Text>
  <Text style = {{fontSize:12}}>{" which is a 15 min walk from you"}</Text>
</Text>
```

I'm trying to alter the line-height of the 2-3 lines of text, but passing the lineHeight prop to the parent, or simply all of the children, has no effect. Is there a proper way of solving this? Or should I take a completely different approach to my text blurb?

To make the desired out come more clear: The text blurb should all be together, as such:

"Tried Beef and Shrimp Fried Noodle for $10.25 at JoyYee Restaurant which is a 15 min walk from you"

In order to keep the multiple text components in line, I had to wrap everything in a parent text; but now I am unable to control the line height of this small paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial: The error lies in the fact that lineHeight is not a prop but is a style of the Text component. Therefore, the proper method was to write:

```
<Text style = {{lineHeight: 30}}>Hello etc. etc.</Text>
```

Hopefully this can help others avoid this issue as well!